# Bigger marker template for RoboEarth

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, roboearth, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to record my shoes, but they are too big for the current marker template. Can I somehow adjust the parameters and use a bigger marker template to record bigger objects? Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59175/bigger-marker-template-for-roboearth/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is the same as http://answers.ros.org/question/47721/roboearth-ar-marker-template-for-recording-larger-objects/#48055

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0